# The usage of "be going to be doing something"

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

> SELLARS: Mrs. Murphy, last night, Alex had a psychotic break. He
>   killed an unarmed colleague and later suffered a seizure. We did
>   everything, everything, we could, but the doctors couldn't save him.
>   Very sorry, Mrs. Murphy. **We're going to be making the announcement**
>   shortly. Sorry. If there's anything we can do for you and David, we'll
>   do it.
>
> Mrs. Murphy: I want nothing from you.
>
> SELLARS: I understand.
>
> Mrs. Murphy: You stay out of our lives. You and your company.
>
> -- Robocop 2014

I think that here **We're going to be making the announcement** is the same as **We will be making the announcement** or **We're going to make the announcement**, right?

Is this usage just a matter of stylistic choice, or making the statement sound more formal? Any nuances implied?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically identical, yes.
The phrase suggests that the thing being done is slightly difficult or laborious in some way, or perhaps that is has previously been delayed for some reason, but it's very subtle.
This is likely to be spoken English, not written.

Comment: I'm very puzzled as to why this has been downvoted. As a native English speaker I consider this to be a correct answer. Perhaps whoever has downvoted this would care to explain why? Downvotes without comments aren't very helpful.

Comment: Downvotes without comments are allowed on this website. I don't know either